# reunite: passive when used as a transitive verb

Tags: prepositions, passive-voice

Collins labels its use as [[**be VERB-ed + with**]](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reunite)

Longman labels it as: [Reunite is usually passive when used as a transitive verb; "be reunited with somebody"](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/reunite) (likewise there's an entry for the idiom "*[be entwined (with something)](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-entwined-with-something)*", for which Wiktionary offers a note "Particularly used in attributive form *entwined*.")

Unlike for example *gather*, Oxford English Dictionary shows the entry for reunite labeled as [**[usually passive]**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/reunite?q=reunite).

What is the reason behind using reunite in so-called "passive" even in a sentence where there's no semantic agent and meaning?

Secondly, is there a pattern that a group of verb such as reunite follow?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104869/discussion-on-question-by-gjc-reunite-passive-when-used-as-a-transitive-verb).

Comment: What John {b. wanted/desired was to reunite - d. *seems is to have reunited} with his family. c. *It was to have reunited with his family that John seems

Answer (score 1):

"**Passives without an agent

Passive structures without an agent are very common. We use these structures when an agent is not important, or is unknown or obvious**:

All applications must be received before 31 July.

The data was analysed and the results have just been published.

I walked to work. The car’s being repaired."

*[Cambridge Dictionary, passive without an agent](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/passives-with-and-without-an-agent)*

My comments moved to my answer:

- The couple were reunited [by circumstances or the situation or their friends]. In passive constructions there is always an implied agent of some sort. –
- They were entwined [by their love] in each other's arms. Both can be attributive: The reunited couple were not happy. The entwined couple were happy. They were reunited [by x] with their families.
- Let us reunite this family today! Not passive, active. The parents were reunited with their children by the NGO. "with" is not part of the equation necessarily.

Passives without an agent are called short be-passives by **Pullum,** who provides an academic explanation;

2.1.1 Short be-passives

> "The by-phrase in a passive (which CGEL calls an internalized
>   complement, because it is internal to the VP but would have been
>   external to it if expressed as the subject of an active clause) is
>   usually omissible, so some passives contain no counterpart of the NP
>   that would have been the subject in the related active. When a passive
>   clause has a by-phrase, as in (4a), I will call it a long passive. **The
>   kind that does not, as in (4b), will be called a short passive.**
>
> (4)   a.  The president's authority has been much diminished by recent
>   events in Washington.
>     b.    **The president's authority has been much
>   diminished."**

Sentence b. above is what I have been saying in this answer. I would add that there is an implied passive. to be reunited with x is a short passive.

- They were reunited with their friends. [short be-passive, no apparent agent]
- They were reunited by fear with their friends. [long passive, agent: by fear]

VERSUS what **Pullum** calls "adjectival passives", which can be ambiguous.

2.2.4 Adjectival passives

> "**The term `adjectival passive' is often applied (perhaps not very
>   felicitously) to active clauses with predicative adjective phrases in
>   which adjective derives from the past participle of a verb and has a
>   passive-like meaning.** **There is frequently an ambiguity between be
>   passives and adjectival ones.** For example, The door was locked is
>   ambiguous: as a be passive it says that at a particular time someone
>   took the action of locking the door, and as an adjectival passive it
>   says that during some past time period the door was in its locked
>   state. Since the complement in this kind of clause is an adjective
>   phrase, verbs other than be can be used (The door seemed locked, as
>   far as I could tell), and so can adjectives derived with the negative
>   prefix un- (The island was uninhabited by humans)."

My answer contains the example: The room was painted. versus The room was unpainted. versus The room was painted [by some agent].

So, the scholarship in this case tallies with the what the Cambridge Dictionary states (given above).

The paper makes for good reading. I recommend it.

All bolding is mine.

Comment: This doesn't even explain why this verb in particular is used in "the passive". You say _the family gathered (together)_, not _was gathered (by the circumstances, the situation etc.)_

Comment: Unlike _gather_, the entry for _reunite_ is labeled as **[usually passive]**, why? https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/reunite?q=reunite

Comment: @GJC Because the state or condition of being reunited must be more important than the fact of reuniting. ***And that "usually passive" only refers to only to**: [usually passive] to bring two or more people together again after they have been separated for a long time; to come together again. "They were reunited", is **more frequent** than "I [or other pronoun] reunited them". Have you reunited any people recently??

Comment: According to OED, it's _​[usually passive]_ for both menings : **reunite A with/and B** _Last night she was reunited with her children_ as well as 
 *reunite (somebody)* _The family was reunited after the war_.

Comment: I believe you are still arguing that *reunited* cannot be adjectival.

Comment: No, I said it was passive and Pullum (an authority to most people here) calls this structure an adjectival **passive**,

Comment: What Pullum calls an adjectival passive is, in traditional terms, a subject complement that functions adjectively. Please read in full *CGEL* Chapter 16, 10.1.3 . . . *Adjectival passives are passive only in a derivative sense, and we will not say that [32ii–iii] in their statal interpretations are passive clauses: they belong to the complex-intransitive construction. The term adjectival passive applies only to the predicative complement, that is, to the AdjPs . . .*

Comment: @TinfoilHat Whoops, you have me so turned around I quoted the **wrong thing**.  I meant to quote this: b. The president's authority has been much diminished.", which he calls a short be-passive. In other words, a passive without an agent. It has the exact same structure as: to be reunited. And "passive when used as a transitive verb." is nonsense. Enough already.

Comment: Could it be that it was labeled as passive instead of adjective because of the attestations of the prepositional intransitive active voices?  I cannot find similar examples to check whether there's a pattern here

Comment: @GJC Your last comment shows me you are not a native speaker. It is a pity that you do not believe what I have said about that quote from Longman's which makes no sense. There is no such thing as: "passive when used as a transitive verb". They reunited the brothers. =an active verb **versus** The brothers were reunited.=a passive verb. The reunited brothers [adjective] were not happy. And because Pearson (who publishes Longman's) is a fascist-like educational publisher, there is no way to communicate with them.